# How to use getLastVisiblePosition?

Tags: android

```
public void onGroupUpdated(NewGroupMessage msg) {
    if (!msg.getGroupId().equals(mGroupId)) {
        return;
    } else {
        boolean lastItemVisible = mList.getLastVisiblePosition() == mAdapter.getCount() - 2;
        updateConversation();
        if (lastItemVisible) {
            smoothScrollToLast();
        }
    }
}
```

I use above code to judge if the last item of `ListView` is visible. If visible, i will scroll the list to the bottom.

It works, but i don't know why i must use `mAdapter.getCount() - 2` instead of `mAdapter.getCount() - 1`. I am sure the header view count is zero.

The ListView also doesn't contains footer views.

Comment: how many headerviews do you have ?

Answer (score 1):

Override the OnScroll method and do the following:

```
 @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView.getAdapter()
                .getCount() - 1
                && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1) != null
                && listView.getChildAt(listView.getChildCount() - 1)
                        .getBottom() <= listView.getHeight()) {
            //PUT THE CODE THAT YOU WANT TO EXECUTE AFTER REACHING TO THE LAST POSITION
        }
    }
```

Probably you are adding footerView at the end of the listview. In order to skip the footerview position you have to -2

Comment: I also print footer view with `mList.getFooterViewsCount`. But found that to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the mAdapter.getCount() will give you total count which starts from 1 but mList.getLastVisiblePosition() will start from zero I suppose you have a header view